# How to Concatenate Multiple Columns in an effective way is sas

Tags: sas

I've eight columns in my have table and I'm concatenating two columns with other six columns as

```
data case;
set case;

stage1_to = cats(stage1_to, ',' , email_to);
stage1_cc = cats(stage1_cc, ',' , email_cc);

stage2_to = cats(stage2_to, ',' , email_to);
stage2_cc = cats(stage2_cc, ',' , email_cc);

stage3_to = cats(stage3_to, ',' , email_to);
stage3_cc = cats(stage3_cc, ',' , email_cc);
run;
```

Now one basis of stages, I'm sending different mails to different user.

Sample Data

```
email_to =  email@to.com
email_cc =  email@cc.com
stage1_to = stage1@to.com
stage1_cc = stage1@cc.com
stage2_to = stage2@to.com
stage2_cc = stage2@cc.com
stage3_to = stage3@to.com
stage3_cc = stage3@cc.com
```

My code Concatenating all the stage columns with email_to and email_cc.

- If to or cc columns of stage are missing then it append the data as
  ",email@to.com" and ",email@cc.com" and system throws the error
  because ",email@to.com" is not a valid email.
- same if email_cc is not given or both email_cc and stage cc column
  has no data in it, it'll only update "," or    "stage2@cc.com,"
  that's again an invalid email.

Kindly suggest me a good approach to resolve all of these errors. On front end, Email_to is mandatory and all other fields are optional. My main goal is to combine stage columns with email_to and email_cc.

Email_to and Email_cc has all

Currently I'm doing this

```
data case_stage1_to_concatenate;
set case;

stage1_to = cats(stage1_to, ',' , email_to);
where stage1_to ne "" and email_to ne "";
run;

data case_stage1_to_update;
set case;

stage1_to = email_to;
where stage1_to eq "";
run;
```

I'm creating two data-sets for each field and then taking union to make them a single set.

Kindly suggest a better approach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `CATX(",", thing1, thing2,...)`

`CATX` will concatenate with a separator, and treat missing values in such a way that you never get two consecutive separators or just a leading or just a trailing separator.